# Consumer Interface in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I am getting an warning at  `Mathod::nonStaticMethod`, "`void is not a functional Interface`.

`Mathod::nonStaticMethod;` shouldn't this work, is this not a method reference?

```
public class Mathod {
  public static void taskDifferentiator() {
    System.out.println("Static Method...");
  }
  public void nonStaticMethod() {
    System.out.println("Non static method is called...");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Consumer nonStaticConsumer = () -> Mathod::nonStaticMethod;
    System.out.println("End of the program..");
  }
}
```

If I change the program below to, what's the issue with the line below `mathod::nonStaticMethod;`

```
public class Mathod {
  public void nonStaticMethod() {
    System.out.println("Non static method is called...");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Mathod mathod = new Mathod();
    mathod::nonStaticMethod; Error: Not a statement
    System.out.println("End of the program..");
  }
}
```

So  `Mathod mathod = new Mathod(); mathod.nonStaticMethod();`
and
`mathod::nonstaticMethod;` are not the same. Am I correct?

Comment: `Consumer<Mathod> nonStaticConsumer = Mathod::nonStaticMethod;`

Comment: `() ->` syntax is used for defining _lambda expressions_, `::` is used for defining _method references_. Don't mix them.

Comment: In case of second approach I still see an error not a statement, I have updated the description above. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 4):

```
Consumer nonStaticConsumer = () -> Mathod::nonStaticMethod;
```

Here you've mixed syntax.

```
Type::someMethod
```

is a different way of writing `x -> Type.someMethod(x)` where the `x` grows or shrinks to account for the # of arguments required / that `someMethod` has, e.g. if it's `public void someMethod(int x, String a) {}`, `Type::someMethod` is short for `(x, a) -> Type.someMethod(x, a)`.

You've *also* used the lambda-syntax arrow notation, so you've combined the two.

`() -> Mathod::nonStaticMethod` thus says: Define a function. This function takes no arguments, and returns the result of evaluating `Mathod::nonStaticMethod`, which is itself a function (so, a function that takes in no arguments and returns a different function).

As with all lambdas (`->`) and method references (`::`), the compiler must take clues from the context to know which functional interface to adapt the lambda/MR to. In this case, you're providing a Consumer, and Consumers take in 1 argument and return nothing (`void`), hence, the compiler is taking the context clue of 'the thing to the right of the arrow is to be treated as `void`), which, naturally, isn't a functional interface. That explains the error 'void is not a functional Interface'.

What you presumably want is either one of these:

```
Consumer<Mathod> nonStaticConsumer = m -> m.nonStaticMethod();
Consumer<Mathod> nonStaticConsumer = Mathod::nonStaticMethod();
```

Either one works fine.

Comment: so 
Mathod mathod = new Mathod();
mathod.nonStaticMethod(); and mathod::nonstaticMethod; are not the same.

Comment: No. The first one is a cake. The second one is a recipe. You can't eat it - but given the recipe, you can make one cake. Or 5. Or 20. Or none. Whereas with the first, you have exactly one cake. You can't make more, you can't choose to make less, as it's already made.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.

1. missing import
2. `Consumer` is a generic class, you need to instanciate that generic.
   What could be the type argument of your `Consumer`? As you wanted to represent a call to instance method `nonStaticMethod()` then surely the type must be `Mathod`. So at least write `Consumer<Mathod>...`.
3. When you want to use a function to represent a code to be catched by a functional interface you need either a lambda-expression or a method reference.

   1. **lambda-expression**. `Consumer<E>` interface has the sole abstract method `void accept(E e)`. So you need a lambda that takes one argument and returns nothing (`void`). Something like `x -> something_returning_void`. As you want to call `nonStaticMethod` you want `x -> x.nonStaticMethod()`.
   2. **method reference**. As `x -> x.nonStaticMethod()` is a lambda that only call a method you can just use `Mathod::nonStaticMethod` (instance method reference).

Full program could be (with calls):

```
import java.util.function.*;

public class Mathod {

  public static void taskDifferentiator() {
    System.out.println("Static Method...");
  }

  public void nonStaticMethod() {
    System.out.println("Non static method is called...");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Mathod m = new Mathod();

    Consumer<Mathod> nonStaticConsumer1 = x -> x.nonStaticMethod();
    nonStaticConsumer1.accept(m);
    Consumer<Mathod> nonStaticConsumer = Mathod::nonStaticMethod;
    nonStaticConsumer.accept(m);
    System.out.println("End of the program..");
  }
}
```